# CakePHP routing with colon separator

Tags: cakephp, routes

I need to create routes that include a colon to produce URLs like `http://app.com/prjct:a9b5c`. Obviously it's currently simple to use a slash instead with the default routing.

```
$SLUG = array('slug' => '[-_A-Za-z0-9]+');
Router::connect('/prjct/:slug', array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'show'), $SLUG);
```

But routes specifications use the colon character as a special indicator, which interferes with my naive attempt to replace the second slash above with another colon.

How do I use colons in this case for a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named parameter as explained in [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/947/Named-parameters). Write code below in your app/config/routes.php:

```
// Parse only the 'prjct' parameter if the current action is 'show' and the controller is 'projects'.
Router::connectNamed(array('prjct' => array('action' => 'show', 'controller' => 'projects')));

// Then set default route to controller 'projects' and action 'show
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'show'));
```

In your projects_controller.php :

```
function show(prjct = null) {
    // Check if prjct match the pattern
    $pattern = '[-_A-Za-z0-9]+';
    if(!preg_match($pattern, prjct)){
        // Redirect somewhere else
    }
    // Rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is indeed out of scope for simple routes. I see two options:

1. Use a custom route parsing class, as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1634/Custom-Route-classes). There isn't a whole lot of documentation on the topic, but you can extend the existing class and play around with it to get a hang of what it's doing. Then customize it to your needs.

   ```
   class MyRoute extends CakeRoute {
       public function parse($url) {
           debug($url);    // input
           $route = parent::parse($url);
           debug($route);  // output
           return $route;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Route these URLs with a catch-all route to a controller, where the parameter will be available as a named parameter in `$this->params['named']`. Do what you need to do there.